# How to add a computer to a Domain of windows server 2022 runing on AWS EC2

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, amazon-web-services, windows

I have Windows server 2022 running in AWS EC2 with the address that the same instance in EC2 generated, this server can be opened perfectly from any location using "Remote Desk
controller" but if I ping the public address of the EC2 instance it doesn't reach it, I am trying to establish a connection to add a PC to the domain using the option of change from wokrstation to Domain, my domain service on Active directory.I don't know if it's a firewall problem or if it's simply not possible because it doesn't belong to the same network segment.

[image: attempt to add PC to domain failed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a computer to a Domain of windows server 2022 runing on AWS EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1118267/how-to-add-a-computer-to-a-domain-of-windows-server-2022-runing-on-aws-ec2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to run a Domain Controller exposed to the internet, you do not want to do so; there's a certain history of security problems, and if a bad actor breaches your DC, they basically have keys to the kingdom.

Typically scenarios such as the one you describe, where you have a domain controller at a different site from your clients, it's solved using a private vpn tunnel. This avoids exposing the DC.

The VPN tunnel can generally speaking be one of two kinds:

- Endpoint to site
- Site to site

Endpoint to site is a VPN established by every individual computer, to reach the central DC.

Site to Site may be from a office location to the cloud location to reach the DC.

What you end up probably depends on other parts of your architecture.